# How to cache a docker image in gitlab pipeline

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration

I want to cache the /var/lib/docker folder on my gitlab pipeline, which I believe will make the docker not build everything again on the second run. It's a self compiled docker file.

```
build_linux:
  tags: 
    - linuxvm
  stage: build
  cache:
    - key:?
      paths:
        - /var/lib/docker
```

What should I put as a key, though? I believe it shouldn't be a file, so I'm a little bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG` which is your branch name